# anchors do not work after adding jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is probably a beginners problem but I can't get my links to work after adding jquery code to animate my anchors' background.
This is the markup:

```
<ul class="nav">
<li> <span id="background"> </span><span id="active"></span><a href="page1.html"     class="active">page 1</a> </li>
<li> <a href="page2.html">page 2</a> </li>
</ul>
```

This is the jquery code:

```
 $("ul.nav a").click(function () {
      $("span#background").fadeIn(800, function () {});
      $("#active").animate({left: "+=2410"}, 950)     
      return false;
    });
```

The "span" elements have background images via css and are dynamically placed within the active `<li>` element.
Thus the active link gets a background and an animated image flying in. 
Now, when trying to click the link to page 2, the right target url appears in the browser, but the link doesn't work. Probably the normal anchor action is being interfered by the jquery code. Is there something i overlooked?

[this is the bare bones testpage](http://www.vuyk.eu/testsite/page1.html)

thanks anyone who has a clue!

Comment: If I click the second link nothing happens; so I'm not sure what you mean by 'the right target url appears in the browser.'

Comment: I mean, that when i hover over the link, the browser shows where it goes when clicking. That's the right page, but it doesn't happen!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return false` kills the click and prevents it from firing.

Comment: Because there is a return false on the click event which kills the click action.

Comment: I commented out the "return false" and put the new files on the testsite. As you can see the link to page2 works however the background images do not show up. What is my second mistake then here?

Comment: I'll try this last question in a new post for clarity

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
$("ul.nav a").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("span#background").fadeIn(800, function () {});
      $("#active").animate({left: "+=2410"}, 950)     
    });
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I changed the code on the testpage (see original post for URL) but it didn't change the behaviour of the link. The default action is what i need: the link should work so it has to send the user to the target page.

Comment: @user1432392 the problem I found that, `#background` and `#active` are within first `li` tag, so `page2` can catch them. It would be better if you append both of them to each `li` and for `background` and `active` use `class` instead of id.

Comment: The id's are being set dynamically, so when page2 loads, these id's are gone within the first <li> and set within the second <li>.

Comment: Addition: on the testpage you will not see this happen on page2 because it is in this case a static bare bones testpage